# QEMU Package Missing

Tags: qemu, github

Our open source project has been using Github Actions to run an Image builder. We are using Ubuntu latest and we have two deps that get updated which are qemu and qemu-user-static. Up until a couple of days ago this was working but now it seems the packages it was and is still trying to request is missing from the repository. The packages are http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/q/qemu/qemu_4.2-3ubuntu6.18_amd64.deb  and http://azure.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/q/qemu/qemu-user-static_4.2-3ubuntu6.18_amd64.deb
There is a package for 6.19 for both of these but I can't work out how to specifically request these packages. Is there a way to request these specifically? Does anyone know who would manage these packages?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The specific packages (6.18/6.19) you linked to are for Ubuntu 20.04, which is two years old, not "latest" by a long, long road. Latest supported would be version 1:6.0+dfsg-2expubuntu1.1, used by Ubuntu 21.10. Latest testing would be version 1:6.0+dfsg-2expubuntu4.

- 6.19 is in the `focal-updates` pocket of the Ubuntu repositories. Check that you really do have focal-updates enabled. Look at the changelog date -- it less than a week, you might be delayed by phased updates (if so, just be patient).

In order to run a specific version of the qemu package, you must satisfy all the dependencies. The simplest way to do that is to run the appropriate release of Ubuntu. That's how Debian-based systems work -- you avoid dependency hell using snapshots when the entire archive is built to a common set of dependencies.

If you try to bolt newer software onto an older release of Ubuntu, it might work. It might not. It might cause unexpected problems. The Debian way to avoid such problems is to upgrade from one snapshot to the next. Each snapshot is a release. Ubuntu releases every 6 months in April and October.

So there's no point "requesting" a package. It's not about permission. It's about dependencies.

If there is really some feature in newer versions of qemu that you want, use a newer release of Ubuntu...or a snap of qemu on an older release. If you merely just want a great recent version of qemu, then use the version apt installs in your 20.04 system.

Comment: Thank you for the information. The environment is in github actions and ubuntu-latest in there = 20.04. I will look further into the focal-updates and perhaps raise a ticket on the github actions repo https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments

Comment: I double checked, but as answered by @user535733 everything should be all right. If in doubt check and report the output of `apt-cache policy qemu-user-static`. I also see you used an azure mirror, if in doubt switch it in `etc/apt7sources.list` to the main ubuntu repo at `http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu` and retry if that is any different.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this fixed it for me

`sudo apt-get install qemu-user-static=1:4.2-3ubuntu6.17`

I actually put this in the `run` section:

```
$ apt-cache madison qemu-user-static
$ sudo apt-get install qemu-user-static=1:4.2-3ubuntu6.17
```

so I know what versions are available